# Optimizing individuals by direct comparison (fitness is dependent on other individuals)

Tags: machine-learning, python, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithms

I'm participating in an AI challenge and would like to use machine learning or genetic algorithms to optimize my strategy. The strategy is represented by a list of floats (size=7) which are weights for specific values. Now, in theory, I only need to find the best set of floats.

Normally, evaluating fitness of an individual in genetic algorithms (for example in DEAP) seems to be done independently of other individuals, while my fitness is directly dependent, as the game is n-player (up to 5).

I could evaluate a population by having it evaluate against a hard coded player, but since the best individual should win against all other, this seems counterproductive.

Currently I use a (python) script that generates 50 AIs with random weights, run the game with all pairs and get a win percentage for each, but I don't know how to mutate the best ones and get a new population, I'd prefer a library that can do this for me.

Comment: Asking for libraries / code, etc., is off topic here. I think your main question is probably on topic, but we'll need more information. How does the game work? What makes an individual more 'fit' than another? Etc.

Comment: @gung I don't think it's important how the game works, my engine returns the placement of each AI, and fitness is just the win percentage